# Supremum of the infimum

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, math-operators

Consider the following snippet:

```
$$\text{d}_{H}(A,B)  = \max\left\{ \sup_{a\in A} \inf_{b\in B} \text{d}(a,b),\sup_{b\in B} \inf_{a\in A}\text{d}(a,b)\right\}$$
```

[image: example]

In the output, the text under the inf's is significantly smaller then the one under the sup's. The same happens when I have it in an `align` environment.

You can see the same problem in the wiki definition of the [Hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance). How can I have the typeset under the inf's and sup's in the same size?

Comment: @Dror with a minimal using amsmath it looks the same to me, can you post a minimal?

Comment: It is not typeset any differently. As Herbert points out, there is a height difference because `inf` does not descend below the baseline. You can add `\let\inf\relax \DeclareMathOperator*\inf{\vphantom{p}inf}` in the preamble to have them be at the same height. You can do the same for `\max` and `\min`, if you want.

Comment: Of course, I meant to say it is not typeset at a different size.

Comment: @Yianis: I am using `amsmath` and it does look odd in my case (same oddness as you can see on the wiki link).

Comment: @TH: It's amazing how illusive it looks. Anyway, your solution worked for me. Is there a reason to keep the old `\inf`? Why this is the behavior for `\max`, `\min` and `\inf` but *not* for `\sup`?

Comment: @Dror: Because max, min, and inf don't have characters that descend below the baseline. As for a reason to keep the old version or not, it's up to you. Herbert says it looks ugly without it. I'm not sure I have an opinion on it. The difference is so slight, that I don't think I'd notice it. So it's up to you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To elaborate on @Philipp's answer: The `mathtools` package provides `\adjustlimits`, which corrects the spacing of the limits of two adjacent operators. In your example, you would use it like

```
\[ \adjustlimits\sup_{a\in A} \inf_{b\in B} \mathrm{d}(a,b) \]
```

[image: example]

Btw, if you are using LaTeX, you should [use `\[ ... \]` instead of $$...$$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) and `\mathrm` or `\operatorname` instead of `\text` for the `d` (so that it will not inherit properties (like italics) from the surrounding text).

Comment: As `\def` seems to be not recommended for regular usage, I believe this is the best solutions. Which also works for me.

Comment: Should there be a closing `\]` in there somewhere?

Comment: @asmeurer: yes, of course.

Answer (score 6):

it is a problem with the depth of `\inf` which is zero. Use it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\Inf{\operatornamewithlimits{inf\vphantom{p}}}

\begin{document}

\[ \text{d}_{H}(A,B)  = \max\left\{ \sup_{a\in A} \Inf_{b\in B} 
   \text{d}(a,b),\sup_{b\in B} \Inf_{a\in A}\text{d}(a,b)\right\} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution also works, but then I have two different definitions for `inf`. This can cause confusions. Do you have a specific reason to keep the original `\inf`?

Comment: sure, it looks ugly when I use it without a preceeding `\sup`

Comment: I see. So the whole problem is caused because of the combination of `\sup` and `\inf` and the `p` in the `\sup`, right?

Comment: @Dror: yes, that is always a problem when having two consecutive operators with limits and not the same depth of the characters.

Answer (score 2):

See section 3.1.4 of the `mathtools` package manual for a description and a generic solution.