# How to change the position of underset?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

In the command:

```
\underset{t \rightarrow x}{\limsup} f(t) = \underset{t \rightarrow x}{\liminf} f(t)
```

I get the `{t \rightarrow x}` lower under the limsup then the liminf (due to the "p" in limsup).

How can I change the position of the underset?

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: Shouldn't that be written as `\limsup_{t \rightarrow x} f(t) = \liminf_{t \rightarrow x} f(t)`? Doesn't solve the problem though.

Comment: I tried that first, but it placed the {t \rightarrow x} to the right of limsup.

Comment: That is usually by design in inline mode. You can override that behavior with `\limsup\limits_{t \rightarrow x} f(t)`.

Comment: Very much related: [Supremum of the infimum](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8218/1235) (possible duplicate).

Comment: @Hendrik: the mathtools solution in the linked question doesn't work in this case though (the other solution works of course)

Comment: @Caramdir: Ah, OK, thanks, so not a duplicate since the mathops are not adjacent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A phantom could be useful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \underset{t \rightarrow x}{\limsup} f(t) = \underset{t \rightarrow x}{\liminf\vphantom{p}} f(t)
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes that works thank you! Is there a general way of adjusting the position though?

Comment: you can also use a `\mathstrut` in lieu of the `phantom`, nothing wrong with your solution either.

Comment: How does the     \mathstrut work?

Comment: @Yiannis: yes. That will also work.