# Uneven subscripts.

Tags: math-mode, formatting, subscripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Supremum of the infimum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8218/supremum-of-the-infimum)

Is there a way to make the subscripts appear evenly in the following code: `\sup_{a\in A}\inf_{b\in B}`?

That is, so that `a\in A` doesn't appear lower than `b\in B` (can't post a sample pic - need more than 10 rep points)?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I've duped here based on the particular situation but also note http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/subscripts-for-primed-variables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you referring to inline or display math? In display mode, the `mathtools` package provides a command to adjust the "limits"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[\adjustlimits\inf_{a\in A}\sup_{b\in B} f(a,b)\]
\end{document}
```

[image: adjusted limits]

Comment: Yes, I was referring to display math. Your solution is great, thank you!