# Align subscripts vertically

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, subscripts

I would like to align the subscripts  in an expression such as this one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}    
$$\sup_{f\in\mathcal H}\lim_{\epsilon\downarrow 0}\sup_{g\in\mathcal H,0<\|g\|<\epsilon} \text{something}$$
\end{document}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: misaligned subscripts]

and I'd like the `\epsilon \downarrow 0` to be on the same line as the other two subscripts.

Comment: Very much related: [Supremum of the infimum](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8218) (possible duplicate).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `mathtools` package provides a trick for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads also amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
\adjustlimits\sup_{f\in\mathcal{H}}\lim_{\epsilon\downarrow 0}\sup_{g\in\mathcal{H},0<\|g\|<\epsilon} \text{something}
\]
\end{document}
```

The `\adjustlimits` command should precede a pair of operators where you want the subscripts to be aligned.

Alternatively, you can define a new operator to be used in cases like these:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\plim}{lim\vphantom{p}}

\begin{document}
\[
\sup_{f\in\mathcal{H}}\plim_{\epsilon\downarrow 0}\sup_{g\in\mathcal{H}, 0<\|g\|<\epsilon} \text{something}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

About avoiding `$$` in LaTeX, please see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Also it's preferable to write `\mathcal{H}` with braces, to make clearer what symbol is involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot! for the `$$', it was just for the MWE :-)

Answer (score 2):

I set \arraystretch outside of the environment, so it will affect everything, but I understand it can also be set inside the environment for local effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}    

Was:
$$\sup_{f\in\mathcal H}\lim_{\epsilon\downarrow 0}\sup_{g\in\mathcal
H,0<\|g\|<\epsilon} \text{something}$$

Is:
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.6}
\setlength\arraycolsep{0.3ex}
\[
\begin{array}{cccl}
\sup & \lim & \sup & \text{something}\\
\scriptstyle f\in\mathcal H & \scriptstyle \epsilon\downarrow 0 & 
\scriptstyle g\in\mathcal H, 0<\|g\|<\epsilon & \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you really sure?

Comment: @egreg p.185 LaTeX User Guide & Reference Manual: "The following style parameters can be changed anywhere outside an array... They can also be changed locally within an item, but the scope of the change should be explicitly delimited by braces or an environment... `\arraystretch`"

Comment: @egreg: Thank you for teaching me something today.  I appreciate it.