# Align consecutive operator subscripts in equation

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I have to write the definition of uniform convergence. That is, the superior limit in the succession's pointwise convergence's set of the limit for *n* to infinite of the absolute value of the difference between the *n*-th function and the limit function evaluated in *x*. More difficult said than done. The fact is, written in LaTeX this way:

```
\[\sup_{x\in I}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|=0\]
```

Results in this:

[image: Uniform convergence]

The range of `\sup` and `\lim` are not aligned, resulting in a rather displeasant appearance. I tried adding `\vphantom`s in the subscripts (just in case the problem is in the capital `I`), but even putting the same subscript in the  `\lim` and the `\sup` changes nothing, the problem is in the `p` letter of the latter which shifts the subscript lower than the other one.

Can anybody tell me how to ignore it?

Comment: potential duplicate: [Supremum of the infimum] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8252/579)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of [`mathtools`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)' `\adjustlimits` command, which is made for exactly this kind of situation.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\(\displaystyle % <--- Just to get correct size of output in standalone class
  \adjustlimits\sup_{x\in I}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|=0
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]